# Displaying/formatting data depending on a conditional on a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I currently have a DropDownList item that receives data from a method via the `SelectMethod` property. The method returns and IQueryable item of a DB table.

I am trying to make it so that I can format what data is displayed on the dropdown per item.

For example, display field `Name`. If that is Null, instead display the `ID` field.

I thought that the way to do it would be via the property `DataTextField` but that just seems to take in the name of the field to display.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share some sample code? I couldn't understand well what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you would like to display Id field if the display field **name** is empty.
if I am right you can handle it in sql statement by using Isnull 
ex.

select IsNull(Description, Id)as Description,Id  from  product